# C program runs on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows

I'm a newcomer to C but have dedicated more time to learning it recently due to a class I'm in, but I'm having a strange issue with my program. The code below compiles on both Linux and Windows, but while running it works correctly on Linux but on Windows it simply skips to "End of Program Execution".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void circumference(int a);               // function prototypes for circumference, area, and volume
void area(int b);
void volume(int c);

int main(void)
{
   // initialize array of 3 pointers to functions that each take an int argument and return void
   void (*f[3])(int) = {circumference, area, volume};

   printf("%s", "Enter 0 to calculate circumference, 1 to calculate area, 2 to calculate volume, and 3 to end: "); // requests user to make choice
   size_t choice;                        // variable to hold user's choice
   scanf("%u", &choice);
   puts("");

   // while loop that checks the user's choice, ending if 3 or greater
   while (choice >= 0 && choice < 3) {
  
        if(choice == 0) {

            circumference(choice);

        } // end if

        if(choice == 1) {

            area(choice);

        } // end if

        if(choice == 2) {

            volume(choice);

        } // end if

        puts("");

        printf("%s", "Enter 0 to calculate circumference, 1 to calculate area, 2 to calculate volume, and 3 to end: "); 
        scanf("%u", &choice);
        puts("");

   } // end while

   puts("Program execution completed.");          // Notifies user of program end

} // end main

 // function for computing the circumference of a circle with user defined radius
void circumference(int a) {

   double radius;                                 // variable for radius
   printf("Please enter a radius: ");             // asks user to enter radius and stores it
   scanf("%lf", &radius);
   puts("");

   double circumference = 2 * 3.14159 * radius;                   // calculates circumference with formula 2πr
   printf("The circumference of a circle is computed.\n");
   printf("       Radius: %lf Circumference: %lf", radius, circumference);    // prints the radius and circumference
   puts("");

} // end circumference

 // function for computing the area of a circle with user defined radius
void area(int b) {

   double radius;                                // variable for radius
   printf("Please enter a radius: ");            // asks user to enter radius and stores it
   scanf("%lf", &radius);
   puts("");

   double area =  3.14159 * (radius * radius);             // calculates area with formula πr^2
   printf("The area of a circle is computed.\n");
   printf("       Radius: %lf Area: %lf", radius, area);   // prints the radius and area
   puts("");

} // end area

 // function for computing the volume of a sphere with user defined radius
void volume(int c) {

   double radius;                               // variable for radius
   printf("Please enter a radius: ");           // asks user to enter radius and stores it
   scanf("%lf", &radius);
   puts("");

   double volume = (4.0/3.0) * 3.14159 * (radius * radius * radius); // calculates volume with formula (4/3)πr^3
   printf("The volume of a sphere is computed.\n");
   printf("       Radius: %lf Volume: %lf", radius, volume);         // prints the radius and volume
   puts("");

} // end volume
```

I've never had this issue before, so I'm a bit stumped as I don't believe I've used anything system specific. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you build on Windows? Have you tried using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to see what happens?

Comment: Please, please attend to several compiler warnings before running the code. Passing a pointer of the wrong type in `scanf` is always wrong. In some compilers `size_t` will be the same size as `unsigned int` but not in others.

Comment: ... but even if `size_t` is different from `unsigned int`, that does not imply that the resulting mismatch with the `scanf` format must *necessarily* produce recognizable misbehavior.  "Undefined" means undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely a mismatch between the `scanf` format `%u`, which is really for `unsigned` types, and your use of the type `size_t` for the variable `choice`.

Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

What is likely happening here is that the size of `size_t` is different from `unsigned` (i.e. `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(unsigned)`). So when you use `scanf` you only write to part of the memory used by the `choice` variable. The remaining memory can then contain some other data, it doesn't matter what, making the actual value of `choice` different from what you expect, so the loop is never entered.

Compilers should have been able to catch this mismatch for `scanf` if you enable more warnings when building. I recommend at least adding `-Wall -Wextra` when building with GCC or Clang, and `/W4` when building with MSVC.

That it happens to work on your Linux system is pure luck. Or perhaps *unluck*. GCC on Linux should definitely be able to detect this problem. And I also recommend you use a *sanitizer* if you can. Add the `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` when building, and you will get errors at run-time when your code does something bad.

---

Finally for the solution: Change the type of `choice` to be `unsigned`:

```
unsigned choice = 0;
```

I also added an initialization of the variable, so it won't have an *indeterminate* value (which otherwise uninitialized non-static local variables will have).

---

On a different note, both `size_t` and `unsigned` are unsigned integer types. Values of such variables can never be negative. So a check like `choice >= 0` will always be true.